# Create multiple dictionaries from lists partitions

Tags: python, list, dictionary, partition

So I have a list:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

And two lists of the form

```
['A', 'B', 'C']  [ 'D', 'E']
```

whose total length sum is equal to the original list (partition). How can I obtain the following dictionaries in Python:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3 } {'D': 4, 'E': 5}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `next` with `iter`:

```
values = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
lists = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']]
itr = iter(values)
result = [{key: next(itr) for key in lst} for lst in lists]
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, {'D': 4, 'E': 5}]
```